# Most efficient way to extract a substring of a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I got a HTML page's content as a PHP string. I want to extract a javascript variable value from that string. I know that the format where the variable is declared in the string will always be:

```
var token = "var_value"; //var_value is alphanumeric
```

Therefore, I tried to find the value between `var token = "` and `";` by using a regex which does that:

```
preg_match("/var token = \"(.*?)\"/", $haystack, $result)
```

The problem is that the string being HTML/JS code, is pretty big to parse (8k+ length in characters) and from [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-match.php)'s documentation we're being told

> Tip
>
> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() instead as it will be faster.

So I went and did that, but I am still concerned whether it's more efficient.

```
$before = 'var token = "';
$after = '"';
if ($t = strpos($haystack, $before)) {
    $tokenstart = substr($haystack, $t + strlen($before));
    $g = strpos($tokenstart, $after);
    $token = substr($tokenstart, 0, $g);       
}
```

First, define the strings that are before and after the needed value, then find the position in the string where the start is located. Then, using [substr()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.substr.php), return the string without everything before the value. Do the same with whatever is after the value: get the starting position of the `"`(there are none of it in my variable as it's alphanumeric) and remove everything after it.

I think `strpos` being more efficient than `strstr` makes this a better approach, because I know the exact format that I need. It also stops on the first occurence of the string rather than finding all of them.

Is there a better a more efficient way to do this?

**EDIT**

Judging from the answers, I made it like the following. One less substr makes a lot of sense. Also added the `false` check, to make sure.

```
if (false !== $ts = strpos($scripttext, $before)) {
    $tokenstart=$ts+strlen($before);
    $tokenend= strpos($scripttext, $after,$tokenstart);
    $token = substr($scripttext, $tokenstart,$tokenend-$tokenstart);
}
```

Check for start, get token position by adding the start length to its position, then search for token end (") in the original string, starting from the token start, then a substr from the start to the end.

Would constructing a string from `tokenstart` to `tokenend` be faster than `substr`?

Comment: note that `strpos` has the offset where the search starts as third parameter. (in other words, you can avoid the first `substr`). Don't forget to test if `strpos` doesn't return `false` like that `if (false !== $t = strpos($haystack, $before))`

Comment: To do it in a more clean way, you should extract all script content with DOMDocument and then use a third party library like jparser or something else. It is a less efficient way, but it is less error prone.

Comment: I already extracted the script part with [SimpleHTMLDOMparser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and I don't need to worry about errors, the format is always the same.

Comment: In this case, use DOMDocument instead of simpleHtmlDom that is well know to be slow.

Comment: I was using simple initially, switched to Goutte that was very slow so I switched back. I'll give DOMD a try, too. However, at this moment I am looking for an efficient way to get the variable value when I have already gotten the script's string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better a more efficient way to do this?

Yes, you can use `strpos`'s *offset* parameter to search the `$after` position starting just after the first double quote. At that point you know the variable's length and may extract the value as you already do (i.e., you need only one `substr()`).

However, I think that at this point any further optimization is likely to be just small change.

Actually, I'm not too sure you need to worry about `preg_match`'s speed - and you are *not* using `preg_match` "just to check", you're also extracting the value.

Comment: Well I DO want to extract the value. I'm extracting it in the second case, too. It is in $token

Comment: Yes. What I meant to say was, this might well be a legitimate case to use `preg_match`. Unless you need to do this very frequently, or the text to scan is really *huge*, it may well be that the greater legibility of a `preg_match` solution is better than the negligible speed advantage of `strpos`.

Comment: Isn't a 8000 characters string pretty huge? And I am doing this pretty often, that's why I need it to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: `preg_match` can also do clever things like ignoring `\"` within the string ;)